# Silverstripe Email sent via Contact Form does not arrive

Tags: email, content-management-system, silverstripe

in a recent project I integrated a custom Contact Form which uses the silverstripe Email Class. Unfortunately the sent E-Mails do not arrive at the client. It seems to depend on the host/domain of the target E-Mail Address. E.g. gmx does work (but spam), but receiving the mails on the E-Mail Address of the client does not work at all (hosted at united domains). Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Email` class in SilverStripe is admittedly not the greatest ;) But apart from potential lowlevel encoding errors, email delivery mainly depends on factors outside of SilverStripe. 
You can start debugging mailservers, DNS records, spam headers, bounce emails, etc - but in the end its probably far easier to leave email delivery to a SaaS-provider like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com). Both have offerings where you can just point your PHP configuration to their SMTP servers. SendGrid has a nice [best practice collection](http://sendgrid.com/resources/best-practice-guides.html) on what to watch out for when sending emails in general.

Comment: hello ingo, in the end i used phpmailer with smtp authentification. worked fine.